# Research behind current design patterns?

Tags: design-patterns, user-expectation, user-centered-design

Recently I have found that so many websites are starting to look the same (logo left, menu right, nav floats, big large cover image (blurred e.g.), flat light design.

Outside of these just being popular patterns. Anyone know of any hard studies that show that they are effective in selling a product / service?

Comment: Effective in what way? Keeping visitors on the page? Selling their product?

Comment: Sorry in selling a product / service. (edited the question)

Comment: There are also sites that don't do that and still succeed. It's about what your users want and the context of the data displayed. It's not just about how it looks, but what is provided to allow the users to move forward in the checkout process. This question seems like a complicated question without knowing more details about what you're doing. What product/service are you selling? Maybe answering that might help us help you.

Comment: this is simply too broad of a question. And I doubt any research could find anything conclusive on such a broad design trend. It's mostly just popular is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you would be interested in the results of e-commerce UX research studies. Some of the current best practices and design trends are derived from these studies.

Here are some conducted by the Nielsen Norman Group about E-commerce. Unfortunately, the majority of them require payment to review the results.
https://www.nngroup.com/reports/topic/e-commerce/

However, this free article does go into some of the e-commerce research found in the above reports though!
https://www.nngroup.com/articles/e-commerce-usability/

Comment: Could you expand on these articles? Perhaps write a summary of what is in them and why it's relevant to the question. Link-only answers are not very helpful and may even become irrelevant due to link-rot.